# Limiting max query execution time, number of connection and readers available to specific user in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, connection, execution-time

Is there any way, and if, how to set arbitrary maximum number of:

- query execution time
- open connection number
- simulatanous data readers

for specific database user in SQL Server 2008?

As for the user he'll be only operating on views with readonly access.

Comment: You could achieve most of this with [Resource Governor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee151608(v=sql.100).aspx) but it depends on which edition you're using - that's an Enterprise feature.

Comment: unfortunatelly it's Standard version